# How to hide first 3 childs of UL using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following structure:

```
<ul id="test">
    <li class="myclass">Item1</li>
    <li class="myclass">Item2</li>
    <li class="myclass">Item3</li>
    <li class="myclass">Item4</li>
    <li class="myclass">Item5</li>
</ul>
```

I want to hide the first three items. I wrote the following code but it only hides the first child and not the next two.

```
#test li:first-child
{
    display:none;
}
```

How do I hide the other two also?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child) selector:

```
#test li:nth-child(-n+3) {
    display: none;
}
```

From the linked MDN doc:

> Matches if the element is one of the first three children of its
>   parent

Answer (score 4):

```
#test li:nth-of-type(1),
#test li:nth-of-type(2),
#test li:nth-of-type(3) {
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS3:

```
#test li:nth-child(-n+4)
{
display:none;
}
```

Keep in mind that this property is supported in all major browsers, except IE8 and earlier.